# My first dynamic SQL insert InvoiceHeader data is it good or need any advice

Tags: c#, sqlite

Make dynamic SQLite insert with invoice header and detail but in InvoiceHeader i made this example but i'm looking for any advice for it
looking for any idea and your advices
thanks

```
public void ExcuteCommand(string TableName, string[,] ColmanNameColValue)
    {
        SQLiteOpen();
        SQLiteCommand QueryCommand = new SQLiteCommand(SQLiteConn);
        string Query = "Insert into " + TableName +  " ( ";          
        for (int i = 0; i < ColmanNameColValue.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            string ColNames;
            if (i == ColmanNameColValue.GetLength(0) - 1)
            {
                ColNames = ColmanNameColValue[i, 0] + " ) ";
            }
            else
            {
                ColNames = ColmanNameColValue[i, 0] + ", ";
            }
            Query += ColNames;
        }
        Query += "Values (";

        for (int i = 0; i < ColmanNameColValue.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            string ParamName;
            if (i  == ColmanNameColValue.GetLength(0)-1)
            {
                ParamName = " @" + ColmanNameColValue[i, 0] + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                ParamName = " @" + ColmanNameColValue[i, 0] + "," ;
            }
            Query += ParamName;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ColmanNameColValue.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            QueryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                "@" + ColmanNameColValue[i, 0], (ColmanNameColValue[i, 1]));
        }
        QueryCommand.CommandText = Query;
        QueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLiteConn.Close();
    }}
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I will say no, this is not good. This method of dynamically concatenating strings is fragile, error prone, difficult to reason about and highly vulnerable to sql injection. There is no error handling and there are disposable resources that are not cleaned up. `AddWithValue` can cause precision issues and performance issues.

Comment: *" This method of dynamically concatenating strings is fragile, error prone, difficult to reason about and highly vulnerable to sql injection. "* if that method is so unsafe how are the "big boys" doing it in their frameworks.. @Crowcoder iám speaking about ORM frameworks in general not only C# as most frameworks provide some kind of Object coding to dynamic SQL generation... The SQL string will be generated by string concatenation and at some point it is going to be parameterized at some point thats for sure.

Comment: @RaymondNijland with lexers and parsers much more sophisticated.

Comment: When I have done something similar to what it looks like you are doing, I query the database for the tables and columns, I do not rely on a user to provide the information. I don't know what management views if any are available in Sqlite but I imagine you can generate an INSERT without needing to be supplied the column names. This also would help guard against someone who can contrive data to cause injection.

Comment: *"with lexers and parsers much more sophisticated."* yes that might be a option with [abstract parse tree to prevent SQL injections](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract%20parse%20tree%20to%20prevent%20SQL%20injections) @Crowcoder the problem is how are you going to detect a valid SQL query without injection and one with as both seams like valid SQL code.. it would mean you would need to have a BNF code of a SQL which is allowed on that running point and compare the trees if they match..